# React component displaying dynamic data based on URL

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to create a single dynamic component that displays data from a json file dependant on the url. Instead of manually creating and storing each page.

For example: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

on page route: `/1`
the page would display:

Title = `unt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit`

Body = `quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto`.

How would I return specific data from the json?
Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pb2tL7ma/

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the question how to extract parameters from the URL? You should look into adding a router like `react-router` to your app, then you can access those parameters based on the `Route`

Comment: @ZekeDroid I know how to extract the url parameter, how would I use the parameter to display one singular piece of data and map it to the component?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

One way of going about it is to use [React Router with URL parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) and create a `Link` for every page in your `pages` array, and use this URL parameter to extract the page you want to view.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyonx83yy0))**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pages: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(res => {
      this.setState({ pages: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { pages } = this.state;

    if (pages.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <ul>
                {pages.map(page => (
                  <li>
                    <Link to={`/${page.id}`}>{page.title}</Link>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/:page"
            render={({ match }) => {
              const pageParam = Number(match.params.page);
              const page = pages.find(p => p.id === pageParam);

              return <div>{page.title}</div>;
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-router-dom`. Add a route in `App.js` like this:

```
<Route path='/posts/:id' component={DynamicData} />
```

And then you can get that `id` in your `DynamicData` component by:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use `react-router-dom` for that or basically just use the [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object. 
It's already available out of the box so you don't need an external dependency.